# NXHTML in Emacs 24

Tags: emacs

I am having a issue where i cant get nxhtml working in emacs 24. I have the correct load path

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "C:/Documents and Settings/stsvyas1/Desktop/emacs/emacs-24.0.94/nxhtml/autostart.el")
```

I have the files in the correct place and doing C-x-C-e will look like it loads it but i dont get any of the nxhtml commands. Does anyone know how to solve this, or what the issue is? thanks

Comment: Is there anything in your *Messages* buffer to suggest that there was a problem?  Does your mode line say you are in nxhtml mode?

Comment: When i type nxhtml then press tab to see the completions and it lists none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh wait.

You don't have the correct load-path at all.

In fact, what you need to do is this:

```
(load "C:/Documents and Settings/stsvyas1/Desktop/emacs/emacs-24.0.94/nxhtml/autostart.el")
```

Comment: Hm i really sure research more into elisp. So the issue was that i was not suppose to do add-to-list but just load? thanks again it worked

Comment: It'll come.  `load' take the argument passed in, and tries to load it as elisp.  `When you're doing the (add-to-list 'load-path ...) thing, what that does is just make it so you can (require 'foo-package).